# Xcode, build failed with the example "hello world" with c++

Tags: c++, xcode, certificate

When looking at the errors i have two of them. They happens directly after i try to run the example code "hello world" and the program does not run.

The first error is:
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'xxx@hotmail.com'. The login details for account 'xxx@hotmail.com' were rejected.

The second error is:
No signing certificate "Mac Development" found: No "Mac Development" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXX" with a private key was found.

The xx and XX is of course censoring.
This seems to be issues with the computer and certificates, how do i solve this?

Comment: Does it also fail if you use Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: It fails with both Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that the issue is unrelated to C++ then.  This Apple dev forum has some guidance: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/67366

Comment: The problem was that Xcode needed me to log in with my apple id again. Now everything is working.